# TinyMCE Converting HTML through API: How to Stop

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, richtextbox, tinymce-4

I have to support editing HTML content that will be used for Crystal reports so I setup the tinyMCE editor to use specific tags.  I have the following formatting customizations:

```
tinymce.init({
           .
           .
           formats: {
              bold: { inline: 'b' },
              italic: { inline: 'i' },
              underline: { inline: 'u' },
              forecolor: { inline: 'font', attributes: { color: '%value' } }
           }
});
```

However, when I call:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(d.Template);
```

And `d.Template` contains the following example HTML:

```
<p>
Welcome to the <b>site</b>.  <i>Thank you</i> for coming.
</p>
```

The problem is tinyMCE is adding the `<b>` tag as `<strong>` and the `<i>` tag as `<em>`.  Is there any way to have tinyMCE use what's defined in the format section, rather than convert HTML to what it expects by default.  I understand why its doing it, but I cannot support those tags currently...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your configuration:

```
extended_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em"
```